# Comparing Values in Multiple Columns and Returning all Declining Regions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that is similar to the following, and lets say I have sales amounts for different regions for two different years:

| Company | 2021 Region 1 Sales | 2021 Region 2 Sales | 2020 Region 1 Sales | 2020 Region 2 Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | 300000 | 150000 | 250000 | 149000 |
| Company 2 | 10000 | 17000 | 100000 | 80000 |
| Company 3 | 12000 | 20000 | 22000 | 90000 |

I would like to compare each region for each year to determine which regions have declined in 2021. One caveat is that the regional sales have to be at least $25,000 to be counted. Therefore, I am looking to add a new column with all of the region names that had less than $25,000 in sales in 2021, but more than $25,000 in 2020. The output would look like this, although there will be more columns or "regions" to compare than 2.

| Company | 2021 Region 1 Sales | 2021 Region 2 Sales | 2020 Region 1 Sales | 2020 Region 2 Sales | 2021 Lost Regions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | 300000 | 150000 | 250000 | 149000 | None |
| Company 2 | 10000 | 17000 | 100000 | 80000 | Region 1; Region 2 |
| Company 3 | 12000 | 20000 | 22000 | 90000 | Region 2 |

Thank you in advance for any assistance, and no rush on this. Hopefully there is a concise way to do this without using if-then and writing out a lot of combinations.

Answer (score 0):

```
number_of_regions = 2 # You have to change this
def find_declined_regions(row):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, number_of_regions+1):
        if row[f"2021 Region {i} Sales"] < 25000 and row[f"2020 Region {i} Sales"] > 25000:
           result.append(f"Region {i}")
    return "; ".join(result)

df.apply(find_declined_regions, axis=1)
```

`df` is your DataFrame and you have to change `number_of_regions` based on your problem.

EDIT:
if columns names are all different, There art two cases:

1- You have a list of all regions, so you can do this:

```
for region in all_regions:
        if row[f"2021 {region} Sales"] < 25000 and row[f"2020 {region} Sales"] > 25000:
```

2- You don't have a list of all regions, so you have to create one:

```
all_regions = [col[5:-6] for col in df.columns[1:int(len(df.columns)/2)+1]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. One question for learning purposes when you have a chance...how would this loop work if the column names are all different?  For example, rather than region 1, region 2, etc., if I had northwestern sales, southeastern sales, etc.

Comment: Edited the answer @nb1214

Comment: Thank you very much, still quite confused when it comes to combining the original answer and the edit, but I have what I need to figure it out now.